# break a Long line in qbyte array into multiple line in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have Following code written

```
    QString WctUtils::getDiskSpace( )
     {
         static QString diskSpaceCmd ( qgetenv("WINDIR")
                           + "\\system32\\wbem\\wmic LOGICALDISK GET Name,FreeSpace,Size,Description/value");

        QProcess proc;
        QByteArray qba;

        proc.start(diskSpaceCmd);


       if(proc.waitForFinished(-1))
         {
          qba = proc.readAllStandardOutput();
          qba = qba.trimmed();
          qba.replace('\r', ' ');
          qba.replace('\n',' ');
          QList<QByteArray> lines = qba.split('\n');

        }

       QString diskSpace(qba);
       return (diskSpace);
    }
```

Output obtained is :

```
 {
     "Service": "20170131184024",
     "diskinfo": "Description=Local Fixed Disk   FreeSpace=421098377216   Name=C:   Size=499875049472         Description=CD-ROM Disc   FreeSpace=   Name=D:   Size=         Description=Local Fixed Disk   FreeSpace=324859035648   Name=E:   Size=487687450624         Description=CD-ROM Disc   FreeSpace=0   Name=F:   Size=553459712",

 }
```

Expected output is

```
      {
       "Service": "20170131184024",
       "diskinfo": "Description=Local Fixed Disk   FreeSpace=421098377216   Name=C:   Size=499875049472       
                   Description=CD-ROM Disc   FreeSpace=   Name=D:   Size=    
                   Description=Local Fixed Disk   FreeSpace=324859035648   Name=E:   Size=487687450624         
                   Description=CD-ROM Disc   FreeSpace=0   Name=F:   Size=553459712"
    }
```

How can I get this Disk info line in Multiple line? how to break a part of qbyte array into multiple lines?

Comment: Look for `" Description="` and turn it into `"\nDescription="`. But it would probably be better solved by not replacing the existing newlines with spaces to begin with. Or at least not *all* of them (if there are extra newlines in the original string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You remove all `\n` symbols from the string yourself, and then immediately try to split it on `\n` separator, of course it is not going to work since there are no `\n` left in the string:

```
qba.replace('\n',' ');
QList<QByteArray> lines = qba.split('\n');
```

One way to do what you want is that @Some programmer dude suggested in the comment. Another way is to split the whole line on `\n`, then you will have an array of strings, with possibly more elements than you need. Then you can iterate over that array (while outputting it to the console or wherever you need to), and only add a newline when you meed the "Description" part:

```
QList<QByteArray> lines = qba.split('\n');
for(const QByteArray& line : lines)
{
    if(line.startsWith("Description")
        cout << "\n" << line.toStdString();
    else
        cout << line.toStdString();
}
```

Comment: I tried out even this   qba.replace('\r', ' ');
          QList<QByteArray> lines = qba.split('\n');    It is still not working